# How to make a gradient circle across top menu in wordpress

Tags: css, gradient

I really, really like the half CSS gradient circle on this wordpress site but I really cannot get it implemented myself. Url is https://admincontrol.com/nl/oplossingen/data-room/

Who can help me with some instructions? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The idea

- A big circle, a div with `border-radius: 100%` and `width:` >= to its container.
- Hide a half of it from the top.
- Center it horizontally.

Make size (`width`, `height`) and positioning (`top`, `left`) relative to its container with `%` units and `position: absolute`, inside a container with `position: relative` for sure.

### Reference

The red area is the viewport (what we see):

[image: reference]

### Example

A responsive one of what you may be looking for:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #e9fff8 59.5%, #a7edd4);
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  /* to avoid hidding the content, we move it a layer back*/
  z-index: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .gradient {
    width: 200%;
    left: -50%;
  }
}


/* Ignore code below */

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks Leo!! You've really helped me to understand how this is done!

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with `border-radius` on a `div` element. If you set it to 50%, the div will get round. Then apply a gradient as `background` and position it on top middle. You can play with sizing as well to achieve a satisfying result.

```css
.gradient-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #53fdff; /* fallback */
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #53fdff, #74ffc1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-circle"></div>
```